Resetting provider's value when a widget is removed from the tree
my problem is very simple that its laughable and i've been losing my mind for the past 6 hours over it.
i have a simple notifier with a provider like this
class LoginSignUpToggleProvider extends Notifier<bool> {
  void toggle() {
    state = !state;
  }
  void reset() => state = true;

  @override
  bool build() {
    return true;
  }
}

final loginSignUpToggleProvider =
    NotifierProvider<LoginSignUpToggleProvider, bool>(
        () => LoginSignUpToggleProvider());

its supposed to be a toggle to switch between the login and the sign up screens in the following code
class _AuthScreenState extends ConsumerState<AuthScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool showLoginPage = ref.watch(loginSignUpToggleProvider);

    return drawScreen(showLoginPage);
  }

  Widget drawScreen(bool showLoginScreen) {
    if (showLoginScreen) {
      return const LoginScreen();
    } else {
      return const SignUpScreen();
    }
  }
}

each screen has a simple button with a
onPressed: () => ref.read(loginSignUpToggleProvider.notifier).toggle()

to switch between each other. very simple and basic stuff.
my issue is that when the user logs in or signs up the AuthSrceen(the widget holding both the login and sing up screens) gets removed from the widget tree and the HomeScreen widget shows up which is what is expected. however i want to reset the **loginSignUpToggleProvider ** so when the user logs out after singing up for the first time and goes back to the AuthScreen, he isnt faced with the signing up page but instead the login page as if theyre opening the app for the first time, aka resetting the value of the **loginSignUpToggleProvider ** by calling the .rest() method on the notifier.
i apologize in advance if my question is too basic but i really need help, ive been trying with chatgpt for the past 6 hours of my life and the documents were too overwhelming and discussed more complex scenarios and it got very confusing to a newbie like myself.
ive tried many things, which i hope someone can explain why none did work.
for starters,

i tried using ConsumerStatefulWidget in the AuthScreen widget to get access to the dispose() method and call ref.read(loginSignUpToggleProvider.notifier).reset(); when the AuthScreen widget gets disposed which always resulted in stateError (Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed.) (this is something chatgpt suggested but after looking deeper ive found out its not allowed to modify providers during the widget's life cycle)

i tried calling ref.read(loginSignUpToggleProvider.notifier).reset(); inside the sign up button so when the user signs up it automatically toggles the provider and shows the LoginScreen the next time they go to the AuthScreen after logging out. however the singing up method immediately switches to the HomeScreen when successful and thus it results in yet another stateError (Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed.)
heres the singing up method for context


 Future signUp(
      {required String email,
      required String password,
      required String surname,
      required String userName,
      required BuildContext context,
      required WidgetRef ref}) async {
    try {
      await _authServices.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

        //trying to rest it here
      ref.read(loginSignUpToggleProvider.notifier).reset();

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (!context.mounted) return;
      showPopup(message: e.message.toString(), context: context, ref: ref);
    }
  }


lastly and in a desperate attempt, i tried going to the parent widget holding both the AuthScreen and the HomeScreen, and thought maybe i can make it reset the loginSignUpToggleProvider when the switch happens

class RootScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return Consumer(
              builder: (context, ref, child) {
                   //trying to rest it here
                ref.read(loginSignUpToggleProvider.notifier).reset();
                return const AuthScreen();
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

which results in "FlutterError (Tried to modify a provider while the widget tree was building.
If you are encountering this error, chances are you tried to modify a provider
in a widget life-cycle, such as but not limited to..." error.

The easiest way would be to use an auto dispose notifier (assuming that no other widget other than the sign in and sign up widgets watch the provider). Autodispose providers automatically destroy their state once there are no widgets watching it. You can learn more about state disposal here
Here's an example of the same code but with an auto dispose notifier.
class LoginSignUpToggleProvider extends AutoDisposeNotifier<bool> {
  @override
  bool build() => true;

  void toggle() => state = !state;
}

final loginSignUpToggleProvider =
    NotifierProvider.autoDispose<LoginSignUpToggleProvider, bool>(
  () => LoginSignUpToggleProvider(),
);

If for some reason, you would not want to use the auto dispose provider, your second approach could also work. The trick is to not use the ref after the widget is disposed. You can obtain the notifier before the async operation and call a method on the notifier after the async operation.
Here's how that would look like in practice:
Future signUp({
  required String email,
  required String password,
  required String surname,
  required String userName,
  required BuildContext context,
  required WidgetRef ref,
}) async {
  try {
    final notifier = ref.read(loginSignUpToggleProvider.notifier);
    await _authServices.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    //trying to rest it here
    notifier.reset();
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (!context.mounted) return;
    showPopup(message: e.message.toString(), context: context, ref: ref);
  }
}

This also applies to context within widgets. You can normally access items like navigator (think Navigator.of(context) before async operations.
